# How can I create a GCP service account with assigned role that will only be valid for a certain period of time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a service account on GCP, then assigning a role that's only valid for 24 hours. What would be the best way to do it?

I'm trying to follow the instruction from the following article, but it sounds like the max is 1 one hour? How can I set it for 24 hours?

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct

Comment: By default, the maximum allowed value is 1 hour. To set a lifetime of up to 12 hours, you can add the service account as an allowed value in an Organization Policy that enforces the constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension constraint. See [detailed instructions at](https://cloud.google.com/iam/help/credentials/lifetime) 

If a value is not specified, the token's lifetime will be set to a default value of 1 hour.

Comment: Credentials has no relation with this. The doc you mention talks about the token generated with the Service Account to access to the services but has nothing to do about removing roles. As well what @AbhijithChitrapu has no the relation too with the main concern since it's about the token but no the SA. Said this there is no a built-in way to revoke roles after some time and you need to build a custom solution to revoke the roles.

Comment: Do you want to create a token with a live duration of 24h? (it's not possible, 12 is the max). Or do you want to grant the access only for 24h? (event is multiple token are requested and used)

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere - I want to grant access to the role only for 24 hour. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu that's the issue though. So max is 12 hours? no way to increase it to 24 hours?

Comment: @Puteri what custom solution would you suggest? Instead of revoking the role, is there a way to make the SA expire after 24 hours?

Comment: Yes you can revoke the SA or the permission after a while

Comment: You can't expand more than 12h the token life duration. 12h is already an exception that you have to enforce with Organisation Policies. It's not secure to have more. Review your design instead

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere did you mean manually? if yes, that's not what I'm trying to do. I want it to to be done on schedule.

Comment: I don't understand your architecture and why you need a token life of 24h. Can you update your question and provide a wider point of view on your current situation to help you to solve the issue differently?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think the op refers to remove the roles in IAM or simply revoke the SA (like when you delete it) let's say the op wants temporary service accounts and not really on focusing on the tokens that can be created with it

Comment: @fokusfocus Something I can think of is a Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Scheduler every hour or whatever and check the service accounts you're interested in. If those are older than 24 hours delete them. As well eventarc can help on this. Anyway asking for this is off-topic but this is an overall idea

Answer (score 1):

In your use case, I recommend you to use [IAM Condition](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) on your service account. The IAM condition is an aspect that you add on the account-role binding. You can add different conditions, especially a time condition.

After a delay, the condition will no longer meet and the role won't be considered as valid when checked. So, the permissions can be considered as removed.

*You can have expiration on an identity (i.e. on the service account) only on the roles that are bound with that identity*